# Inserting data into mysql database via jFrame

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jframe

I am learning how to connect a mySQL database to a jFrame. I can connect to the database, but I am unable to insert what I write in a text field in a column in the database.

Database connection:

```
public void conectBD ()
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/prototipo","julia","julia");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println ("Database conectado com sucesso");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) 
    {
          System.out.println ("Database não conectado");
    }

}
```

inserting data:

```
private void SalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try{
    conectBD ();
    String paciente = nomes.getText();
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO paciente (nome) VALUES ('"+paciente+"')");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "paciente Salvo!");
    nomes.setText("");
        }                                        
catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
{ }    
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring exceptions. Don't do that, at minimum log the exception or use `e.printStackTrace()` so you know what is going on. Also, don't concatenate values into a query string, that makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection, use a prepared statement with parameters instead. Update your question to provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I was able to connect to the database. Thank you for the tips!